# MSTest Dynamic Methods to Crawl Web Site

Tags: c#, mstest, dynamicmethod

I am trying to create a MSTest to crawl a web site.  I want it to be dynamic, so I can just throw it into a build for any of our sites.  It's basically a step to test before pushing to a staging environment.  It checks for broken links and missing resources.  Our unit tests are done in MSTest currently.  We're using Bamboo to do our automated builds and tests.  It has a nice format for results.  I want to be able to see each item as a test with the details.  That's easy enough in itself.  I have all the code I need to crawl the web site.

How do create a method with the attribute TestMethod on the fly and include it in the test?  Right now, I have a test method for the four types of resources I am looking for, so there are four test methods.  I want to test method for each unique item.

I have been looking at DynamicMethod, but I don't think that will get me to where I want to be.